# Getting the ratio of a in b

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the current code I have, the issue is clearly that I can't divide strings by strings, but I'm unsure of how to go about editing the code to get it to run.

```
def Fraction(c, s):
    #Returns the fraction of 's' formed by 'c'.
    return c / s
print(Fraction("a", "ababab"))
```

In theory, 0.5 should be printed; `'a'` forms half of all text in `'ababab'`.

Comment: could you explain why it should print 0.5?

Comment: a makes up half (0.5) of the total string.
there are 6 characters in the string and 3 of them are a.

Comment: So you want the *ratio*, not a fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want a ratio here; a number between 0.0 and 1.0 indicating what percentage of a larger string is using a smaller string:

```
def ratio(c, s):
    return (float(s.count(c) * len(c))) / len(s)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def ratio(c, s):
...     return (float(s.count(c) * len(c))) / len(s)
...
>>> ratio("a", "ababab")
0.5
>>> ratio("ab", "ababab")
1.0
```

Comment: That works, I was just naming it in accordance to the requirements. Works nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: The naming is rather.. confusing, because there is a [`fractions.Fraction()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) in Python.

Comment: hmm, alright, I'm still very much new to all of this and just trying to fall in line with what the function must be named.